# Updating filtered data frame in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Can't find why updating filtered data frames are not working. The code is also not returning any error message. I'd be grateful for hints, help.

So the problem comes when i want to update the dataframe but only to given selection.
Given .update function on data frame objects updates the data based on index from 1 data set based on another. But it does not do anything when applied to filtered dataframe.

Sample data:

df_1

```
index   Name    Surname 
R222    Katrin  Johnes      
R343    John    Doe
R377    Steven  Walkins 
R914    NaN NaN
```

df_2

```
index   Name    Surname 
R222    Pablo   Picasso     
R343    Jarque  Berry
R377    Christofer  Bishop
R914    Marie   Sklodowska-Curie
```

Code:

```
df_1.update(df_2, overwrite = False)
```

Returns:

df_1

```
index   Name    Surname 
R222    Katrin  Johnes      
R343    John    Doe
R377    Steven  Walkins 
R914    Marie   Sklodowska-Curie
```

While below code:

```
df_1[(df_1["Name"].notna()) & (df_1["Surname"].notna())].update(df_2, overwrite = False) #not working
```

Does not apply any updates to given data.frame.
Return:
df_1

```
index   Name    Surname 
R222    Katrin  Johnes      
R343    John    Doe
R377    Steven  Walkins 
R914    NaN NaN
```

Looking for help on solving and why is this happening like so. Thanks!

Comment: `update` apply modifications in place so if you select a subset of your dataframe, only the subset will be modified and not your original dataframe.

Comment: So need replace NaNs? Answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: If need replace only missing values by another DataFrame use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df_1.fillna(df_2)
#alternative   
#df = df_1.combine_first(df_2)

print (df)
         Name           Surname
index                          
R222   Katrin            Johnes
R343     John               Doe
R377   Steven           Walkins
R914    Marie  Sklodowska-Curie
```

---

It not working, because update subset of DataFrame inplace, possible ugly solution is update filtered DataFrame `df` and add not matched original rows:

```
m = (df_1["Name"].notna()) & (df_1["Surname"].notna())
df = df_1[m].copy()

df.update(df_2)

df = pd.concat([df, df_1[~m]]).sort_index()
print (df)
             Name  Surname
index                     
R222        Pablo  Picasso
R343       Jarque    Berry
R377   Christofer   Bishop
R914          NaN      NaN
```

Possible solution without `update`:

```
m = (df_1["Name"].notna()) & (df_1["Surname"].notna())

df_1[m] = df_2
print (df_1)
             Name  Surname
index                     
R222        Pablo  Picasso
R343       Jarque    Berry
R377   Christofer   Bishop
R914          NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Well i knew i m working on something less complex than i thought it is... thanks jezrael

Answer (score 0):

`update` apply modifications in place so if you select a subset of your dataframe, only the subset will be modified and not your original dataframe.

Use `mask`:

```
df1.update(df2.mask(df1.isna().any(1)))
print(df1)

# Output:
             Name  Surname
index                     
R222        Pablo  Picasso
R343       Jarque    Berry
R377   Christofer   Bishop
R914          NaN      NaN
```

Comment: little misunderstanding out here but overal thanks for providing concept of the solution.  Originaly i wanted to update only NA values based on selection criteria.  Thanks for the explanation!